# C Python: Running Python code within a context

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, cpython

The Python C API function `PyEval_EvalCode` let's you execute compiled Python code.  I want to execute a block of Python code **as if it were executing within the scope of a function**, so that it has its own dictionary of local variables which don't affect the global state.

This seems easy enough to do, since `PyEval_EvalCode` lets you provide a Global and Local dictionary:

`PyObject* PyEval_EvalCode(PyCodeObject *co, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals)`

The problem I run into has to do with how Python looks up variable names.  Consider the following code, that I execute with `PyEval_EvalCode`:

```
myvar = 300
def func():
    return myvar

func()
```

This simple code actually raises an error, because Python is unable to find the variable `myvar` from within `func`.  Even though `myvar` is in the local dictionary in the outer scope, Python doesn't copy it into the local dictionary in the inner scope.  The reason for this is as follows:

Whenever Python looks up a variable name, first it checks `locals`, then it checks `globals`, and finally it checks `builtins`.  At *module scope*, `locals` and `globals` are the SAME dictionary object.  So the statement `x = 5` at module scope will place `x` in the the `locals` dictionary, which is also the `globals` dictionary.  Now, a function defined at module scope which needs to lookup `x` won't find `x` within the function-scope `locals`, because Python doesn't copy module-scope locals into function-scope locals.  But this normally isn't a problem, because it can find `x` in `globals`.

```
x = 5
def foo():
   print(x) # This works because 'x' in globals() == True
```

It's only with *nested* functions, that Python seems to copy outer-scope locals into inner-scope locals.  (It also seems to do so lazily, only if they are needed within the inner scope.)

```
def foo():
   x = 5
   def bar():
      print(x) # Now 'x' in locals() == True
   bar()
```

So the result of all this is that, when executing code at *module scope*, you HAVE to make sure that your global dictionary and local dictionary are the SAME object, otherwise module-scope functions won't be able to access module-scope variables.

But in my case, I don't WANT the global dictionary and local dictionary to be the same.  So I need some way to tell the Python interpreter that I am executing code at function scope.  Is there some way to do this?  I looked at the `PyCompileFlags` as well as the additional arguments to `PyEval_EvalCodeEx` and can't find any way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't actually copy outer-scope locals into inner-scope locals; the documentation for [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#locals) states:

> Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

Here "free" variables refers to variables closed over by a nested function.  It's an important distinction.

The simplest fix for your situation is just to pass the *same* dict object as `globals` and `locals`:

```
code = """
myvar = 300
def func():
    return myvar

func()
"""
d = {}
eval(compile(code, "<str>", "exec"), d, d)
```

Otherwise, you can wrap your code in a function and extract it from the compiled object:

```
s = 'def outer():\n    ' + '\n    '.join(code.strip().split('\n'))
exec(compile(s, '<str>', 'exec').co_consts[0], {}, {})
```