# Where does Python store the name binding of function closure?

Tags: python, closures, python-2.x, cpython

So recently I understand the concept of function closure.

```
def outer():
    somevar = []
    assert "somevar" in locals() and not "somevar" in globals()
    def inner():
        assert "somevar" in locals() and not "somevar" in globals()
        somevar.append(5)
        return somevar
    return inner

function = outer()
somevar_returned = function()
assert id(somevar_returned) == id(function.func_closure[0].cell_contents)
```

As much as I understand, the objective of function closure is to keep an active reference to the object, in order to avoid garbage collection of this object. This is why the following works fine :

```
del outer
somevar_returned_2 = function()
assert id(somevar_returned) == id(function.func_closure[0].cell_contents)
assert id(somevar_returned) == id(somevar_returned_2)
```

The thing is (always as much as I understood) before the execution of the `inner` function, Python rebuild the locals variables dictionary. This dictionary will contains :

- the function's closure names associated to their cell contents
- the function's parameters names associated to their default value or the parameter given (and it can overwrite the precedent names)

The question is where do Python store the name binding of the closure ? I can't find it anywhere.

Note: the function's attributes :

```
>>> print "\n".join("%-16s : %s" % (e, getattr(function, e)) for e in dir(function) if not e.startswith("_") and e != "func_globals")
func_closure     : (<cell at 0x2b919f6bc050: list object at [...]>,)
func_code        : <code object inner at [...], file "<stdin>", line 4>
func_defaults    : None
func_dict        : {}
func_doc         : None
func_name        : inner
```

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly... `function.func_code.co_varnames`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>This depends on the python implementation. I assume you mean CPython.</sup>

The `__code__` (or `func_code`) has a `co_freevars` attribute that contains the name of all non-local variables (they are called "free vars" as if a python function was a logical formula where the arguments and local variables are quantified variables)

From these various attribute you can obtain a mapping from local and non-local names to cells.

```
In [35]: function.__code__.co_freevars
Out[35]: ('somevar',)
```

The `co_varnames` attribute lists all locally define names:

```
In [36]: function.__code__.co_varnames
Out[36]: ()
In [37]: def outer():
    ...:     somevar = ["stackoverflow"]
    ...:     def inner():
    ...:         x = 1
    ...:         somevar.append(5)
    ...:         return somevar
    ...:     return inner
    ...: 
    ...: function = outer()

In [38]: function.__code__.co_varnames
Out[38]: ('x',)
```

While `co_cellvars` says which local names are used by *inner* functions:

```
In [43]: outer.__code__.co_cellvars
Out[43]: ('somevar',)
```

All closure functions have `__closure__` attribute. This attribute returns a tuple of cell objects. And The cell object has `cell_contents` attribute which stores the value of variable.

```
In [44]: function.__closure__
Out[44]: (<cell at 0x7f4e06b002b8: list object at 0x7f4e06b522c8>,)
In [45]: function.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[45]: ["stackoverflow"]
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Can you just validate / explain how the local dictionnary is rebuild from the parameters and the closures names ?

Comment: @FunkySayu I'm looking into it. It seems like `locals()` will call [`PyEval_GetLocals`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l4433) which calls [`PyFrame_FastToLocalsWithError`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/frameobject.c#l867). The thing I don't understand about it is that it references a `co_localsplus` attribute that doesn't seem to be available from python. Anyway you can see that it uses `co_varnames`, `co_freevars` etc. to build the `locals` dictionary.

Comment: Maybe it would be great to open another question about it ? Your answer already fit with the question.

Comment: Added tags `cpython` and `python-2.x`.