# What determines which variables are enclosed in a closure?

Tags: python

How does Python decide which vars to enclose? You can see when a variable is defined as a name, it is happily closed, but when defined using `locals()`, it is not closed.

Works great:

```
def outer():
    x = 5
    print(x)
    def inner():
        return x
    return inner()


print(outer())
```

Doesn't work:

```
def outer():
    locals()['x'] = 5
    print(locals()['x'])
    def inner():
        return locals()['x']
    return inner()
print(outer())
```

Comment: I guess in inner locals has only things local to inner, and x is available otherwise in the scope. So that return x would work in latter version too.

Comment: Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32221772/10302746

Comment: Ah, ok, so it searches what exists in the outer scope at time of creation?

Comment: Well, for starters, `locals()['x']` *doesn't even create a local variable*. But in any case, closures are created when the function is *compiled*.