# Executing Python code with a custom local dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a follow-up to [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265756/c-python-running-python-code-within-a-context), I'm experimenting with executing Python code as if it were in the context of an outer function.  I do this by simply wrapping a block of code with `def outer():`, and doing some simple string processing to properly indent the inner code.  Then I compile it and execute the compiled inner code by executing the first code object in the `co_consts` list.

Example:

```
mycode = """
print("Hey!")
"""

wrapped_code = 'def outer():\n    ' + '\n    '.join(mycode.strip().split('\n'))
compiled_code = compile(wrapped_code, '<str>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code.co_consts[0], {}, {})
```

This executes the code `print("Hey")` from within the context of an outer function.  (If anyone is wondering why I'm doing this, it's part of a C extension module I've been working on.) 


**Question**: A problem I run into is that if I wrap code in an outer function, and then execute the inner block of code, I don't seem to be able to pass any local variables to the execution context.

```
mycode = """
print(locals())
"""

wrapped_code = 'def outer():\n    ' + '\n    '.join(mycode.strip().split('\n'))
compiled_code = compile(wrapped_code, '<str>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code.co_consts[0], {}, {"foo" : "bar"})
```

This outputs:

```
{}
```

Notice that I explicitly passed a local dict containing `{"foo" : "bar"}` to `exec`, yet when it actually executes the code and prints `locals()`, it shows an empty dictionary.  Why didn't Python use the dictionary of local variables I passed it?

Comment: "If anyone is wondering why I'm doing this, it's part of a C extension module I've been working on." - That doesn't answer the question. No extension module I've ever seen does this.

Comment: See [Include/code.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/Include/code.h#l35) and [Objects/frameobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/Objects/frameobject.c#l693) (`PyFrame_New`, 693-710).

Comment: @eryksun, thanks.  Your comment solved my problem.  All I needed to do was set the `co_flags` variable in the function code object to `0`, so it would use the locals dictionary I passed it, rather than create a new local dictionary for the execution frame.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a function as the first parameter to exec. A function will define it's own locals, so that's the locals you are printing. Remove the wrapping (which I can't see any use of whatsoever) and it works.

Comment: Is there a way to access/manipulate the function local dictionary?

Comment: @Channel72: From outside the function, no. Because it's local. You are barking up the wrong tree, and should post a question about the problem you are actually trying to solve by using exec(). You almost never need to use exec().